# Able to invoke function directly but unable to curl the exposed POST http endpoint

Tags: aws-lambda, spring-cloud, serverless-framework

While I am able to run https://github.com/mbsambangi/aws-java-spring-cloud-function-demo as is (by invoking the function), it isn't working when I introduce a http event to the serverless.yml.

The modified serverless.yml file is below

```
service: sls-aws-java-spring-cloud-function-demo
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: java8
  timeout: 10
package:
  artifact: target/aws-java-spring-cloud-function-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-aws.jar
functions:
  members:
    handler: com.healthfirst.memberfunction.AwsLambdaHandler
    environment:
      FUNCTION_NAME: members
    events:
      - http: 
          path: /
          method: POST
```

This is happening with other functions too. Am I missing something or is it a bug?

The error

```
curl -X POST https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.yyyyyy.amazonaws.com/dev/ -H "Content-type:application/json" --data '{"memberId":"1234567890"}'

{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

Comment: Your curl command seems to be incomplete. Can you please correct that?

Comment: Are you able to test it directly from the AWS Console and/or from some API client such as Postman ?

Comment: @Imran - corrected the curl command.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Have tried it. Same error from postman, curl from command line and from the API gateway (the boxes view)

Comment: Check the CloudWatch log for your Lambda function. There is probably an uncaught exception being thrown